# How can I avoid `#if DEBUG` directives for members in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-compilation, idioms

I use a log property in my class that is intended only for debugging purposes.

**Note:** I do not use any existing logger packet, as I manage a large lists of objects each of them having its own (!) log.

As it is not used in release mode, it is enclosed by a preprocessor directive:

```
#if DEBUG
    public List<LogItem> DebugLog { get; }
#endif
```

Unfortunately, I need to initialize and copy this property a few times, leading to messy code like this:

```
    public MyClass(object parameterA, object parameterB, ...,
#if DEBUG
        , List<LogItem> debugLog
#endif
        ) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Whilst for actual logging, I wrote a `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` method, I am not aware of any possibility avoiding this ugly and idiom-violating directives for noting arguments and parameters. The [ConditionalAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute) appears to be only applicable on properties and attributes.

I am wondering whether there is any design pattern for this problem enabling a better readability. I am looking forward to your ideas!

Comment: This is the first time in my life I see a `List<Log>`, that's very weird. Why exactly aren't you just calling your conditional logger?

Comment: Create a different implementations of logger class for usage in `Debug` and `Release` mode and initialize it only once

Comment: There are plenty of libraries/nuget packages for logging. Why are you rolling your own?

Comment: You might also consider an AOP approach (aspect oriented programming).

Comment: Best option would be using an existing Logger. But if you need to do it on your own you could use a factory pattern and implement a Log.GetLogger() which will return either a production or debug logger depending on current context. You would set the context on startup e.g. in static costructor of the Log class.

Comment: I am sorry for the unclarity of my description: I am creating a big number of prototype-objects (candidates for final objects), each of them having an own log so that I can trace how and when they are rejected. (So I cannot use a singleton object here.) Is this possible by any existing logger packet?

@PavelAnikhouski You mean an empty Logger class in Release mode? 
Feels a bit overhead-like, but an interesting idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), which is probably the most popular open-source logger for .NET. One of the many benefits you'll see is that you can configure the logger once, in your config file, and have different configurations for debug and release. That way, switching to release is done automatically when you publish the web site or app, you don't have conditional directives in your code, and you don't need to change the code to account for different situations.

Comment: How does this answer the question? You answer with log4net, I will answer with SeriLog which I find far superior. Noone asked for a library

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sure, serilog would do just as well, as would many other packages. TheOP asked how to avoid the conditionals in the code, and using a package would allow that. I wasn't aware of a specific requirement not to use a package, and as using one provides all the benefits the OP wanted, it seems to me to answer the question very well.

Comment: I wouldn't have downvoted if you had stayed neutral and said "you could use one of these many packages" (and there are WAY too many of them) or something along those lines. Recommending the one you like the most isn't neutral, is opinionated. Anyway, the OP asks for a design pattern and @dymanoid commented one good option

Comment: Please see my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416699/how-can-i-avoid-if-debug-directives-for-members-in-c#comment97561910_55416699), do I assume rightly that `log4net` is not suitable for this use case?

Comment: @KnorxThieus you could hammer one of the logging packages (log4net or any other) into doing this but no, if you need separate logs for each object, then they may not be suitable, unless you are prepared to filter the logs afterwards. It might be worth editing your question to clarify your requirements, someone may know of something more suitable